# Is "anyways" a correct word in English?

Tags: word-usage, spelling

I have seen many people use "**anyways**" in chat and comments on SE. But I think I have read in many books as "**anyway**".

Which is the correct word?

[This](https://www.google.co.in/url?url=https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anyways&rct=j&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjyp9mL8PDSAhWHuI8KHcIvDaMQFghWMAU&q=is+anyways+a+word&usg=AFQjCNGyoxUwEPqjML475KfLqFwxC0Y5Lg) suggests that "anyways" is an informal language.

> Definition of anyways 
>   [1] 
>   US, informal:  anyhow, anyway 
>   [2] 
>   (a) archaic:  anywise 
>   (b) dialect:  to any degree at all

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anyways

Comment: Probably about as correct as "anyhoo".

Comment: @Andrew: Quite. I'd have thought that ***anyhoo*** was originally a dialectal *Scottish* usage, but it's been enthusiastically taken up in the US in recent decades (mainly, imho, because it keeps turning up in cartoons like *The Simpsons, Family Guy, American Dad,* etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I figured we started saying it because we were getting tired of "anyways".  Although I never picked up on the Scottish connection, to me it sounds more Southern American.

Comment: @Andrew: It's definitely more AmE than BrE today, but M-W says of the origin: [*probably originally jocular appropriation of Scots and Ulster **onie-hoo = anyhow**.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anyhoo)

Comment: The more research you can demonstrate in your question, the less likely it will be close-voted. In this case, you ought to have at least done some look-ups in a [dictionary](http://onelook.com/?w=anyways&ls=a) and told us what you found there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "In recent decades"?? Is 50 years ago recent? My mom and her sisters said **anyhoo** all the time.

Comment: I would regard **anyways** as a genitive-of-transition.

Comment: Its been in use since 1800, with a peak around 1920 and then again in recent years: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anyways&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canyways%3B%2Cc0, but miniscule if compared to anyway: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anyways%2C+anyway&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canyways%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyway%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano: I said it's been *enthusiastically taken up in the US in recent decades*, as shown by [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anyhoo&year_start=1955&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canyhoo%3B%2Cc0) for the last meaningful half-century in NGrams. But [BrE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anyhoo&year_start=1955&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canyhoo%3B%2Cc0) actually *fell* during that period. Your mom and her sisters are presumably diehard dialectalists, who predated *Family Guy*, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Our local dialect is Irish influenced.

Comment: @TRomano: Well, there you go. In an Ulster accent, ***anyhow*** sounds like ***anyhoo*** to me anyway [anyhow, arnyhaw!].

Comment: @FumbleFingers: They used **anyhoo** as a segue only. Other times they said it normally.

Comment: @TRomano: I think that's nearly always the case, yeah. But personally I'd nearly always use ***Anyway...*** as a segue (often with heavy stress on an over-extended first syllable to catch attention).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I disagree with @mstorkson. I believe that many teachers (including mine) would mark it as misspelled word, but it's actually debatable to say it's entirely wrong. This is what I found in *New Fowlers Modern English Usage*

> *any ways, anyways.* As an adverb = 'in any way, in any respect, at all', used <...> in many literary contexts during 
>   the last four centuries. It seems to have
>   dropped out of standard UK use now, though it survives in regional use. It is 
>   also encountered (always written as one word, *anyways*) in informal AmE.

So according to the book, I think it's acceptable in some dialects and informal contexts. But avoid using it in academic writing.

Answer (score 16):

Technically? No. Will people 100% understand what you mean when you say it, and will you hear many people say it? Yes, absolutely.

The way in which English has developed makes the idea of "correct" words kind of laughable. But if you're writing something formal to highbrow people, avoid using "anyways"

Comment: Common spoken (American) English is plagued by errant trailing 's' sounds in words like forward(s), backward(s), toward(s), and anyway(s).

Comment: @Davo: Actually, that's not true. AmE massively favours ***toward*** where the BrE standard usage is ***towards***, as shown by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toward%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ftowards%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctoward%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ftowards%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28toward%3Aeng_us_2012%20/%20towards%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28toward%3Aeng_gb_2012%20/%20towards%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0) plotting the relative ratios of the two forms in the AmE/BrE corpuses.

Comment: I expect that the Google **Books** NGram viewer is more representative of the written word than it is the spoken. My comment was about spoken AmE. But point taken, I think.

Comment: @Davo: Granted, the usage split is less extreme plotting [*toward/towards **me said***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toward+me+said%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ftowards+me+said%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctoward+me+said%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ftowards+me+said%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28toward%20me%20said%3Aeng_us_2012%20/%20towards%20me%20said%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28toward%20me%20said%3Aeng_gb_2012%20/%20towards%20me%20said%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0) to focus on *spoken* contexts. But it's still the same preference.

Comment: How about formal low-brow people?